# Electricity consumption in fan

Tags: electricity, power

Does regulation in a fan vary in Electricity consumption? i.e. I want to know exactly, is the energy consumption **more** when regulator is tuned to **highest** number or **lowest** number?

Comment: Put a powermeter on the plug ;)

Answer (score 2):

The power generated by a wind turbine is [proportional to $v^3$](http://www.energy-fundamentals.eu/15.htm). Turbines use wind to generate power, fans simply operate on the reverse principle - generating wind using power. Therefore, the power consumed by a fan is proportional to the cube of the wind speed it generates.

Comment: You have not understood my question, what I wanna know is at what spped will be the electricity consumption is max. (high speed or low speed)?

Comment: Well if the power consumption is proportional to the cube of the wind speed, higher speed means more electrical power is needed. To answer you directly: high speed uses greater consumption.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that "highest number" on your fan means "turning fastest", then the only thing we can say for sure is "the faster the fan moves the wind, the more energy it has to give to the air". The kinetic energy of air goes as $\frac12\rho v^2$ per unit volume, and the volume of air moved will also increase by the velocity (imagine a column of air of length $v\cdot 1\mathrm{s}$ being accelerated every second). This means the power given to the air will scale with $v^3$. We can *deduce* that the fan will convert more electrical energy to kinetic energy when at the highest number - and this means that it will consume more power at the highest number.

Note on power regulation: there are several different ways to achieve this. Most modern devices use a switched mode approach: the regulator turns on for a short part of the AC cycle, and thus draws power for only part of the cycle. This works well for incandescent lamps, motors etc which have a lot of built in "inertia" so you don't notice they are being turned on and off 100 or 120 times per second (or 50, 60 - depending on the location and method of switching). It's very efficient - little power is lost in the switch, although you need some filtering to prevent noise spikes on the power supply.

The second method is to place a constant (resistive) load in front of the actual power load (in this case, the fan). The result of this will be to decrease the current through the fan, but it increases the power dissipation in the resistive load (rheostat). When the resistance of the rheostat is equal to the resistance of the fan, they share the power equally and this means that only half of the power consumed goes to the fan (that's the most inefficient setting). However, since the resistance to the electrical supply is smallest when the rheostat resistance is zero (full power), you will still have the greatest power consumption at the maximum speed setting ($P=\frac{V^2}{R}$).

A third method is to use a variable transformer - this was the method of choice for large power systems (like theatrical lighting) in the days before high power solid state switches became cheap and reliable. Again, the regulator consumes only a small fraction of the total power consumed.

Answer (score 0):

In general, yes, as you increase the speed of the fan the electrical consumption increases.  This applies to most techniques for regulating fan speed.

There are oddball cases (with poorly-designed speed controls) where the opposite can occur, however.  These would mostly be with very old fans with resistive speed controls.

And there is a curious case that occurs with squirrel-cage fans (and some others) where if you "stall" the fan (completely block airflow) fan speed increases while power consumption goes down.